# Exclude "general" group from email

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, customer-group

In the observer i want to exclude the General Group from getting an email when group is change.

Observer

```
 <?php
 class Group_Model_Observer
 {
    public function sendEmail(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        Mage::log('I am coming here');

        $customer=$observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        if($customer->getId()){
            if($customer->getOrigData('group_id')!=$customer->getData('group_id')){

                $senderName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/name');
                $senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/email'); 
                $sender = array('name' => $senderName,'email' => $senderEmail);
                $recepientEmail = $customer->getEmail();
                $recepientName = $customer->getFirstname().' '.$customer->getLastname();    
                $store = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

                $storeObj = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());

                $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('customer_group');

                $groupname = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($customer->getData('group_id'))->getCustomerGroupCode();
                $vars = array('customerName' => $recepientName,'customerEmail' => $recepientEmail,    'customerGroup'=>$groupname);

                $translate  = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
                $emailTemplate->setSenderName($senderName);
                $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($senderEmail);
                $emailTemplate->setType('html');
                $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Congratulations your now part of the Squad!');
                $emailTemplate->send($recepientEmail, $recepientName, $vars);

                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);



            }
        }      
    }   
 }
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this if condition after the definition of `$groupname`.

```
$groupname = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($customer->getData('group_id'))->getCustomerGroupCode();

if ($groupname == 'General') {
    return;
}
```

It checks if the group name is "General". If so the method just ends.